# Comparing graph networks in qgraph()

Tags: r

I've got two network graphs, and I'd like to be able to **visually** compare them.

Is there a way of overlapping them/displaying the difference in associations in qgraph()?

Thanks!

```
library("qgraph")
data("big5")

big5_sub1 <- big5[1:249,1:10]
big5_sub2 <- big5[249:500,1:10]

qgraph(cor(big5_sub1))
qgraph(cor(big5_sub2))
```

Answer (score 0):

To visualize the difference you could literally subtract the two correlation matrices and then just plot the difference. Then each edge is the amount of difference between the two nodes. Not sure that it's particularly statistically acceptable to do that, but just to visualize the difference this is how I'd do it:

```
library("qgraph")
data("big5")

big5_sub1 <- big5[1:249,1:10]
big5_sub2 <- big5[249:500,1:10]
cor1 <- cor(big5_sub1)
cor2 <- cor(big5_sub2)
cor.diff <- cor1-cor2
qgraph(cor.diff)
```